# php/mysql - counting and grouping

Tags: php, mysql, count, case

I have a database with played games and their scores. Now i want to run an query that counts all the results for each team with over x scored goals total (home and away combined).

Database structure:

```
+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| HomeTeam | AwayTeam | HomeTeamGoals | AwayTeamGoals |
+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| team1    | team2    |             3 |             1 |
| team3    | team4    |             1 |             2 |
| team1    | team3    |             4 |             4 |
| team4    | team2    |             0 |             1 |
+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
```

Wanted results:

```
+-------+----------+--------------------+
| team  | played   |  games > 3.5 goals |
+-------+----------+--------------------+
| team1 |        2 |                  2 |
| team2 |        2 |                  1 |
| team3 |        2 |                  1 |
| team4 |        2 |                  0 |
+-------+----------+--------------------+
```

I was looking at something like this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS total FROM games WHERE homeTeamGoals + awayTeamGoals > 3.5 GROUP BY homeTeam
```

But that only does it for the home games, so i need a way to also add the away games to this.

Comment: expected result for `team4` is wrong. No match for `team4` has total goals more than 3.5. One match of team4 (with team3) has total goals = 3, and another match (with team2) has total goals = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get results for a team as `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` separately.
- Combine the results using [UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)
- Use the results as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html).
- `Group by` on the **Derived Table** for a **team**, to get the results.

Try the following (**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1847a/1)**):

```
SELECT derived_t.team, 
       SUM(derived_t.played) AS played, 
       SUM(derived_t.games)  AS 'games > 3.5 goals'
FROM 
(
  SELECT t1.HomeTeam as team, 
         COUNT(*) AS played, 
         SUM( IF(t1.HomeTeamGoals + t1.AwayTeamGoals > 3.5, 1, 0) ) AS games  
  FROM your_table AS t1 
  GROUP BY t1.HomeTeam

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT t1.AwayTeam as team, 
         COUNT(*) AS played, 
         SUM( IF(t1.HomeTeamGoals + t1.AwayTeamGoals > 3.5, 1, 0) ) AS games  
  FROM your_table AS t1 
  GROUP BY t1.AwayTeam
) AS derived_t
GROUP BY derived_t.team
```

Comment: Works perfectly :) Thanks! Also reading up on the union all and derived tables!